# Use External Services in a Flow

Tags: community

I have done everything clear as per the challenge but it is still showing me this Error.

**We can't find the correct settings in the 'account update?' decision. Make sure it was created according to the requirements, including correct target references for 'account created' (pointing to the update_user_account Update Records step) and 'account updated' (pointing to the assign_updated_account Assignment step).**

Answer (score 0):

Check this part:

[image: part of the flow with decision]

For me was helpful that list:

- Dont miss Assignment step
- "Update Records" really update right record (Challenge check it)
- Decision outcomes not mixed ("Account updated" = default outcome)

To check it - try "Debug" run, unit contains good sample debug log.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things are the potential issue cause here:

- Flow is not activated.
- You have multiple versions of the same flow and for some reason, it does not matter which one is active, the assignment cannot be passed on my end till I remove/delete the previous versions of the flow.
- There seem to be a delay between new account creation and availability of that account for the assignment test.

Reason why I mentioned all above - I lost a couple of hours trying to find the issue and then gave up for that day. Came back the next day and it worked right away and I passed the assignment without any additional modification.